# is GCC STL thread-safe?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, thread-safety

I found contradictory information on the web:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html

> The SGI implementation of STL is thread-safe only in the sense that
>   simultaneous accesses to distinct containers are safe, and
>   simultaneous read accesses to to shared containers are safe. If
>   multiple threads access a single container, and at least one thread
>   may potentially write, then the user is responsible for ensuring
>   mutual exclusion between the threads during the container accesses.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html

> The user-code must guard against concurrent method calls which may
>   access any **particular library object's state**. Typically, the
>   application programmer may infer what object locks must be held based
>   on the objects referenced in a method call. Without getting into great
>   detail, here is an example which requires user-level locks:
>
> All library objects are safe to use in a multithreaded program as long
>   as each thread carefully locks out access by any other thread while it
>   uses any object visible to another thread, i.e., treat library objects
>   like any other shared resource. In general, this requirement includes
>   both read and write access to objects; unless otherwise documented as
>   safe, do not assume that two threads may access a shared standard
>   library object at the same time.

I bolded the imporant part - maybe I dont understand what they mean by that,when I read object state  I think of STL containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I updated the libstdc++ docs a while ago, it now says (emphasis mine):

> The user code must guard against concurrent function calls which access any particular library object's state *when one or more of those accesses modifies the state.*

Answer (score 4):

How I understand this:

both documents say the same in different manner. MS STL implementation (actually Dinkumware one) says almost the same as your quoted SGI doc. They mean that they did nothing to make STL objects (e.g. containers) thread-safe, most probably because this would add an overhead unnecessary in many single-threaded applications. Any object is thread-safe in their terms, you can read it from multiple threads.

Also docs guarantee that STL objects are not modified under the hood in some background threads.

Answer (score 2):

The information you cite is not contradictory. STL libraries should be safe to be used in a multi-threaded environment (actually, I've worked with one implementation where it was not the case) but it is users' burden to synchronize access to library objects. For instance, if you create a set of ints in one thread and another set of ints in another thread and you don't share either of them among threads, you should be able to use them; if you share an instance of a set among threads, it's up to you to synch the access to the set.

Comment: Actually they are. One says that simultaneous reading of a shared library object with no guards is safe, as long as no one modifies the object. The other one says that any simultaneous access is unsafe.

Comment: @n.m. Yes: "and at least one thread may potentially write" indicates what you are saying. I focused on the fact that the SGI implementation guarantees safe simultaniuos access to distinct objects, whereas the GNU documentation warns about dangers of accessing the same object from multiple threads.

Answer (score -1):

STL is no more. It is superseded by the C++ Standard Library. If you use the ISO C++ and the Standard Library, you should read (a) the Standard and (b) documentation that comes with your implementation of C++.

SGI STL documentation is mostly of historical interest, unless you for some reason actually use SGI STL.

Comment: @MSalters: That's true, but my assertion still stands.

Comment: @n.m: Of course you are correct, but the ISO Standard (at least the 1998/03 version) does not even mention threads and we need to work with concrete library implementations that offer some level of thread safety.